# The name 'Trace' does not exist in the current context MonoDroid

Tags: xamarin.android, trace, system.diagnostics, build-error

So I am compiling a small project in MFA and I am getting the error "The name 'Trace' does not exist in the current context". I have imported System.Diagnostics and according to [THIS](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/assemblies) article, System.Diagnostics is included... Any ideas as to why I am unable to build? I tried the FQDN System.Diagnostics.Trace, but I get an error saying that Trace is not part of System.Diagnostics. Any ideas on where it is for MFA?

Comment: Don't know but the API docs seem to imply there isn't a Trace or TraceSource. There is a Debug class and a TraceListener's class though, http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aSystem.Diagnostics.Debug maybe those would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like System.Diagnostics.Debug does what I need it to, however I am not sure if it is the recommended replacement...